# Resetting imported Python module variables

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand why instantiated module variables will not reset after they have been modified once after they are imported. I've been working with `minimalmodbus`, and I am trying to reset the Baud rate if the default does not match the connected device's. Setting my own default, I cannot get the re-initialization of of `minimalmodbus` to change the baud rate. For example:

```
import minimalmodbus
minimalmodbus.BAUDRATE=9600
comm=minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM4',1) #baud rate set to 9600 here for comm
minimalmodbus.BAUDRATE=19200
comm=minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM4',1) #attempting to change baud rate
print comm #displays all information, and showing that baudrate=9600, not 19200
```

I've had this issue using several other modules and I would really like to understand why this is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you use a given serial port, `minimalmodbus` [creates a `serial.Serial` instance using the current value of `BAUDRATE` and saves it](https://github.com/pyhys/minimalmodbus/blob/master/minimalmodbus.py#L101):

```
def __init__(self, port, slaveaddress, mode=MODE_RTU):
    if port not in _SERIALPORTS or not _SERIALPORTS[port]:
        self.serial = _SERIALPORTS[port] = serial.Serial(port=port, baudrate=BAUDRATE, parity=PARITY, bytesize=BYTESIZE, stopbits=STOPBITS, timeout=TIMEOUT)
    else:
        self.serial = _SERIALPORTS[port]
        if self.serial.port is None:
            self.serial.open()
    ...
```

Even if `BAUDRATE` changes later, future attempts to use that serial port will use the old `serial.SERIAL` instance with the old baud rate.

I don't know what the Modbus protocol is like or how you're supposed to use this module, so I can't tell you how you're supposed to do what you're trying to do or whether it's a good idea. In any case, now you know what's happening.

Comment: I had completely forgotten the correlation between MinimalModbus and Serial. Thank you!